# How can i get the sum of odd and even number with input user in Array C++

Tags: c++

Our programming activity is to construct a C program that creates an array of size 12 and then display separately the sum of even-indexed cells and odd-indexed cells as well as their average. The sample run must be like this.

Sample Run:
Enter 12 elements:  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Sum of even-indexed cells: 6

Sum of odd-indexed cells: 6

Average: 6.0

However, i'm having a trouble getting the sum of odd and even numbers. Like how i can make the program identify the odd and even placing in the array? Do i need to add "if-else" Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int A[11],B[11],C[11];
int sum,ave;
int x;
main()
{
cout<<"Enter 12 elements A: "<<endl;
    for(x=0; x<11; x++) 
        cin>>A[x];

cout<<endl<<"Sum of even-indexed number: "<<endl;
    for(x=0; x<=11; x++){
        cout<<B[x];
    }           
cout<<endl<<"Sum of odd-indexed number: "<<endl;
    for(x=0; x<=11; x++){
        cout<<C[x];
    }
                    
cout<<endl<<"Average: "<<endl;
    for(x=3; x<3; x++)
    ave += B[x]+C[x]/A[x];
        cout<<A[x]<<" ";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(x=0; x<11; x++) cin>>A[x];` — You are reading just 11 numbers. Moreover, why are you defining arrays of 11 elements, when you want to work with 12 numbers? Also, where do you think you calculate the sums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need 3 arrays. Just an array for the elements and 2 variables for the sums of evens and odds.

You could check the position in the array by checking if the remainder of the index divided by 2 equals 0.

You could also start an even position and increment the index by 2 so it would only check the even positions. For the odd positions you do the same, increment by 2 but start at an odd position.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array[12];
    int evenTotal = 0;
    int oddTotal = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++) {
        cin>>array[i];
        cout<<array[i]<<" ";
        if(i%2 == 0){
            //If we consider indexing with 0 to 11
            // If we consider indexing with 1 to 12
            // than this condition will be odd
            evenTotal += array[i];
        }
        else {
            oddTotal += array[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    // Because we have 6 evens and odds
    int average = (evenTotal + oddTotal)/12;
    cout<<"Even Total = "<<evenTotal<<"\n";
    cout<<"Ödd Total = "<<oddTotal<<"\n";
    cout<<"Average = "<<average;
    return 0;
}
```

Check for output here : https://ideone.com/msYFh5